# Can't retrieve values from OrderedDictionary

Tags: winforms, collections

```
        OrderedDictionary ordered = new OrderedDictionary();
        ordered.Add('a', "something");
        ordered.Add('b', "someone");
        ordered.Add('c', "somewhere");


        foreach (char Character in ordered.Keys)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ordered[Character].ToString());
        }
```

I cannot get items by their key. With this code it throws

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

It takes char 'a' as 97 as an integer value and tries to get value by index but what is the reason for this?

If I use `object` in my loop ınstead it works. Why?

```
      foreach (object Character in ordered.Keys)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ordered[Character].ToString());

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.aspx) has two overloads for its indexer: one that take an `int` index and the other that takes an `object`.

C# is trying to convert you `char` type to fit one of those overloads and the one that it is choosing is to convert `char` to `int` (because the compiler sees that as "easier" to do) and thus makes the assumption you are accessing it by index.  The solution is to be explicit:

```
ordered[(object)Character].ToString());
```